# Bulk insert on Postgres table without lock

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds

Hi I am planning to perform a bulk insert from table1 to table2.

table1 has 21 millions records which needs to be inserted into table2, which has 1000 records.

Would like to know if the bulk inserts would cause an entire table lock on table2.

Is there a way to find out if the sql query will potentially lock the entire table? (block any additional new writes to the table)

Comment: Why do you think that an INSERT (bulk or not) would cause a table lock? I have never seen that, but maybe I missed something

Comment: In community PostgreSQL, bulk inserts do not require a stronger lock than regular inserts do.  There might be some forks/extensions which do so, but I kind of doubt it.

Comment: There would be no issue of lock during INSERT then?

Comment: No, and you can test this yourself and you could also check the manual about this subject: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES

Comment: "*I know that bulk inserts would cause an entire table lock on table2*" - how do you _know_ that? Where did you read that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i have edited the question. I guess it is bulk UPDATE query that can potentially lock the table

Comment: An UPDATE will also not lock the table - only the rows that were changed by the UPDATE